# Deploy solution using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, feature, feature-activation, stsadm

I have a solution with 4 projects to automatically some processes in Sharepoint.these projects are:

- WebPartProject: Create a custom webpart
- CreateTemplate: Create 2 documents libraries (with columns), a simple List (and columns) and a Page to put WebPartProject's webpart and the previously document libraries and the simple list in this page.
- WorkflowOne: Put a workflow in one of the previous document library
- WorkflowTwo: Put another workflow in the same document library that previously.

So, When I deploy this solution in VS, everything works.... But When I try to deploy this solution using powershell, doesn't work.

I use the following scripts:

- stsadm -o addsolution -filename CreateTemplateSolution.wsp ------> Operation completed succesfuly
- stsadm -o deploysolution -name CreateTemplateSolution.wsp -immediate -allowGacDeployment ------> Timer job successfully created

And when I go to  Site Actions --> Site Settings --> Site Actions --> Manage site features, 
I can find my solution, I put his status to Activated, restart IIS.... But When I open Sharepoint, I can't find anything.... :(. Am I missing something?????

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Do you see the solution listed as deployed in the farm solutions in central admin after you have deployed it through powershell ?

Comment: Is this SP2007 or 2010? You might be using powershell interface but essentially you are running legacy stsadm commands (..that's OK but in 2010 PS is the way to go). Did you browser to the web part gallery and see yourcustom web part or provision a new site off your template to see it. Your 4 projects, do they equate to 4 features?

Comment: Yes Anthony in 2010.... And yes, every project has his own feature....

Comment: Moss I can't see this menu in central admin...

Comment: Central Admin > System Settings > Manage Farm Solutions

Comment: Hi Moss, I can see my solution in farm solutions.... I don't know what is the reason that i can see it in sharepoint